# Unity project with examples, how to organize it

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm starting learning Unity game engine, and I would like to create a project with multiple examples.

In your opinion how I should organize it?
Is there a "Solution file" like in Visual Studio that you can add projects inside?

The only way that came to my mind is to create a project and a scene for each example but I don't know if this method would be optimal from a references perspective.

I would like to have isolated examples like:

- Rotate around object.
- Chase object.
- Follow mouse cursor.

Thanks for sharing.
Best Regards.
Jose.

Comment: It’s too subjective. If you plan people learning from them it’s best to have clean code and so they can follow it. If it’s just to show off something where they don’t look or only see compiled. Then it’s what works for you and anyone working with you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like to do something like this.

```
string gameMode = "Rotate"; // or other modes when start

void Update(){
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R)){
        gameMode = "Rotate";
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C)){
        gameMode = "Chase";
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F)){
        gameMode = "Follow";
    }
    if(gameMode == "Rotate"){
        linesForRotate...
    }
    if(gameMode == "Chase"){
        linesForChase...
    }
    if(gameMode == "Follow"){
        linesForFollow...
    }

}
```

This may not be the best use, but it may give you a new idea. If i did any mistake in my sentences, sorry for this because my English not so good :) Have a nice day :)

Comment: Im just looking the way to organize the files in directories and project structure not at programming level. But thanks for your answer.